# amorphous silica (diatomaceous earth) dissolution and precipitation using household bleach or ammonia

Tags: aqueous-solution

I'm a layman not a chemist. My question is whether it's possible to dissolve amorphous silica in room temperature water mixed with a commonly available alkaline household product and then have it precipitate naturally out of solution over a few days or weeks. To dissolve a kilo of amorphous silica, what would be the right amount of over-the-counter laundry bleach or household ammonia and room temperature water?

I'm looking for a way to prevent nests of tiny stinging red fire ants under patio pavers that will be laid on sand and jointed with sand. Diatomaceous earth (amorphous silica) is said to be fatal to ants when they come into contact with it, so I wondered if spraying the screeded sand underlayment *in situ* and also the sand in the joints until it was quite wet with the diatomaceous earth solution might do the trick.

I also thought it would pose [a lower health risk](https://pubmed.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/11876495/) and involve much less discomfort to mix up a batch while wearing a respirator and gloves than to work with the diatomaceous earth in powder form, mixing it dry with the sand, over the several weeks it will take me to lay the pavers.

Comment: Silica is not soluble in soda or any alkaline solution at rhom temperature. It can be  dissolved and transformed into a silicate solution in concentrated NaOH solutions but only at high temperature (above 100°C) and under pressure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once it's been [wet, diatomaceous earth is less effective](https://gardenerspath.com/how-to/disease-and-pests/diatomaceous-earth/), so putting it into water, even as a suspension, defeats it's purpose. For that matter, it needs to be reapplied if wet by rain or damp earth. According to [BugTech](https://www.bugtech.com/diatomaceous-earth-benefits-as-a-natural-pesticide/), "sharp edges make tiny cuts in an insect’s exoskeleton upon contact, and the diatomaceous earth then absorbs the oils and fats from its outer layer." If the silica is wet, it will hydrophilic, not oleophilic, and would not absorb oils.

Non-chemistry suggestion: disperse it with air. Use an old container from "talcum" (now starch, for safety) powder, or a container for boric acid insecticide. These squeeze containers are designed to spray out the powder, propelled by air. Diatomaceous earth is [sold in air-spray bottles](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06X952WC5), too. It *might* be feasible to use a sandblasting gun on large areas, with proper respirator -- though at the risk of silicosis.

Comment: Is it because the rain washes the diatomaceous earth powder off the leaves that it becomes ineffective for gardeners? Or does the moisture interfere with its effect on the membranes of the bugs, possibly by "sheathing" the microscopic sharp edges?  In my case, I was thinking of placing the powder *under* pavers where it would not be washed away by rain but it would almost always be damp.

Comment: @Tim, it likely would be ineffective under pavers... see edited answer.

Comment: I can't tell from my reading whether the ant dies from desiccation that results solely from its exoskeleton being pierced by the sharp edges of the diatomaceous earth or as a result of the *combined effects* of that exoskeleton piercing and the desiccant qualities of the diatomaceous earth.  If the latter, then damp DE won't kill the ants, as you said, since it won't be drawing moisture from the ant.

Comment: Here's an article on recent developments in *hydrophobic* silica applications:  https://journals.ashs.org/hortsci/view/journals/hortsci/45/9/article-p1349.xml That type of amorphous silica might be better suited to my ant-killing requirements in a damp environment.  But the article speaks of greenhouse humidity, not outright wetness.

Comment: Found this patent relating to insecticidal use of hydrophobic silica, though it mentions "humidity" not wet soil: https://patents.google.com/patent/US3159536A/en

Comment: Patent on the use of silica gels in damp conditions to control insects:  https://patents.google.com/patent/US5192545A/en